# jQuery - Action when screen width is smaller than 640 pixels

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to do two things when the screen width is smaller than 640.

1. Remove the `home-thumb` class from the `thumbnail` element ... which for some reason is not working. The alert works fine. Am I doing something wrong when trying to remove the class?
2. Change the image `src` from `src="images/235x/654-1.jpg"` to `src="images/335x/654-1.jpg"`

> HTML

```
 <div class="thumbnail home-thumb">                 
   <a href="item?id=654">
    <img class="col_2_img column" src="images/235x/654-1.jpg" alt="">   
   </a>
 </div>
```

> JS

```
 if ($(window).width() < 640) 
 {
    alert("640");
    $("div.thumbnail").removeClass("home-thumb");
 }
```

Comment: you want to change the src as and when you resize or the for smaller screens..

Comment: For some reason ... none of the answers work. Does it matter if the thumbnail elements are loaded dynamically with ajax? And the `(window).width` code is below the append function?

Comment: can u paste your code sequence

Comment: I'm sorry ... but it just occurred to me that I can do `<div class="thumbnail '+($(window).width() < 640 ? "" : "home-thumb")+'">` when populating the elements. And I can do the same for the folder size.

Comment: _"I'm sorry ... but it just occurred to me that I can do <div class="thumbnail '+($(window).width() < 640 ? "" : "home-thumb")+'"> when populating the elements. And I can do the same for the folder size. "_ Does this resolve Question ? What is "folder size" ?

Comment: see point 2 in my question. Not folder size. .. folder. My fault. It does resolve my problem, but I m sure that all of your answers will help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($(window).width() < 640) 
 {

    $("div.thumbnail").removeClass("home-thumb");
     var src_img=$("div.thumbnail").find("img").attr("src");
     if(src_img=="images/235x/654-1.jpg")
     {
         $("div.thumbnail").find("img").attr("src","images/335x/654-1.jpg");

     }

 }
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/n85axdtr/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try using `toggleClass()` and `resize` events:

```js
var onResize = function() {
  $("div.thumbnail").toggleClass("home-thumb", !(640 > $(window).width()));
};

$(window).on('resize load', onResize);
```

```css
.thumbnail {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  background: orange;
}
.home-thumb {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumbnail home-thumb">Thumbnail</div>
```

Comment: Nice ... toggleClass works. But why won't removeClass work?

Comment: When you resize the window and width exceeds 640, you never added the class `home-thumb` to it again.

Comment: @ciprian, kindly accept the answer as it worked for you